# Start multiple brokers in kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

Beginner in kafka and confluent package.I want to start multiple brokers so as to consume the topic.
It can be done via this setting -
 `{'bootstrap.server' : 'ip:your_host,...',}`

This setting can be defined in the server config file or else in the script as well.

But how shall I run those?. If I just add multiple end points to the bootstrap servers, it gives this error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Each listener must have a different name, listeners: PLAINTEXT://:9092, PLAINTEXT://:9093

Comment: You can't run multiple brokers using the same port... That is what the error is telling you. Please see http://kafka.apache.org/quickstart#quickstart_multibroker

Comment: I've started multiple brokers. But the default head is on the port 9092. It keeps it as default and doesnt use the one on 9093 port.

Comment: That's fine because bootstrap servers never needs every single broker. Where the producer data goes depends on the key of the Kafka message

Comment: By the way, if you're using `confluent start`, that'll only ever start one broker. It won't make a Kafka cluster of more than one, even if you run it twice, the listeners will always be on port 9092

Comment: I'm using the command kafka-server-start with its properties.
and the same with zookeeper with its properties.
Started 2 servers like this with different properties(broker.id and listeners and logs file) on port 9092 and 9093.
But the consumer only connects to 9092 even if I mention both of them in the bootstrap.servers config.

Shouldn't the two servers be connected so that even if the leader goes off, the next one will be elected by itself? This is done by the listeners config in the server properties right?

Comment: Do we need to start 3 node zookeeper for a 3 node cluster?
https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/docker/docs/tutorials/clustered-deployment.html

Comment: Zookeeper requires a quorum for leader election. This means 2n+1 nodes must decide on a values, where n is the total Zookeepers. In production, that value is typically 5 or 7 because if you have only 3, and one goes down, then you only have 2 left, and quorum cannot be made... 7 is the limit, though, and I've seen tens to hundreds of Kafka servers sharing that many Zookeepers

Answer (score 3):

```
cp config/server.properties config/server-1.properties
cp config/server.properties config/server-2.properties
```

config/server-1.properties:

```
broker.id=1
listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9093
log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs-1
```

config/server-2.properties:

```
broker.id=2
listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9094
log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs-2
```

**[Reference: kafka_quickstart_multibroker](http://kafka.apache.org/quickstart#quickstart_multibroker)**

Answer (score 1):

Done.
I had actually mentioned same port for producer and consumer and hence was the issue.
Set up brokers on different ports and works fine even if one broker goes down.