# How to set up multiple broker nodes?

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I tried the following -
`./confluent start` which gives-

> This CLI is intended for development only, not for production
>   https://docs.confluent.io/current/cli/index.html
>
> Using CONFLUENT_CURRENT: /tmp/confluent.w1S9B10m 
>   Starting zookeeper
>   zookeeper is [UP] 
>   Starting kafka
>   kafka is [UP]
>   Starting schema-registry 
>   schema-registry is [UP]
>    Starting kafka-rest
>   kafka-rest is [UP]
>   Starting connect
>   connect is [UP] 
>   Starting ksql-server
>   ksql-server is [UP]

After this, `./kafka-topics --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 3 --partitions 3 --topic users` to create 3 partitions for the topic "users". But this gives the error-

> Error while executing topic command : Replication factor: 3 larger
>   than available brokers: 1.   [2018-10-03 02:47:19,079] ERROR
>   org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidReplicationFactorException:
>   Replication factor: 3 larger than available brokers: 1.
>   (kafka.admin.TopicCommand$)

How do I set up 3 brokers? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50773941/start-multiple-brokers-in-confluent-kafka) post is similar but I have no idea how to implement it.

**Edit**
Now I am using `./confluent start` and then `kafka-server-start /path/to/server-1.properties` and server-2.properties on different linux terminal windows. But I get a "JVM cannot allocate memory" error when I try to start server-2.

> OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO:
>   os::commit_memory(0x00000000c0000000, 1073741824, 0) failed;
>   error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
>
> There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to
>   continue.
>   Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 1073741824
>    bytes for committing reserved memory.

Comment: It's not clear if you're using 3 servers or only one... The Apache Kafka documentation shows you exactly how to run two broker processes on one machine. Same rules apply to Confluent... If you're following the Confluent documentation as you mention, you should not be using `confluent start`

Comment: @cricket_007 could you please elaborate. Now I am using `./confluent start` and then `kafka-server-start /path/to/server-1.properties` and server-2.properties on different linux terminal windows. But I get  a "JVM cannot allocate memeory" sometimes. So I was looking for a solution that always works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now I am using ./confluent start and then kafka-server-start /path/to/server-1.properties and server-2.properties on different linux terminal windows. But I get a "JVM cannot allocate memeory" sometimes.

You're getting out of memory because you're starting a total of 3 brokers, 1 Zookeeper, 1 Schema Registry, 1 Kafka Connect Server, 1 Kafka REST server, KSQL server, for a grand total memory usage of somewhere **over** 8 GB... If you downloaded Confluent Enterprise, then you would get Control Center alongside that for even more usage.

It's highly recommended not to run every single service on a single machine, anyway, or even multiple Kafka brokers on a single machine, because if you only have one disk, then you're going to be IO bound by one instance anyway

If you only want Kafka, you do not need the confluent cli command. Run Zookeeper start command, then run Kafka start command.

[You're welcome to start either of those in separate terminals on different ports and pointing to different storage locations](http://kafka.apache.org/quickstart#quickstart_multibroker), but still, both are memory intensive applications, so you should be giving them lots of available heap space (on Apache Kafka page it says at least 6G in a production deployment)

Answer (score 1):

You're getting that error because you've requested a replication factor of three, but only have a single broker. Since Kafka can't meet the requested replication factor (since you don't have >= 3 brokers) it refuses to create the topic.

There are [steps shown here](https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/installing_cp/index.html#production-environments) for installing a multi-node environment. Two other relevant docs:

- http://kafka.apache.org/quickstart#quickstart_multibroker
- http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#basic_ops_cluster_expansion

If you just want to use a single broker (e.g. for dev) you could reduce the replication factor:

```
./kafka-topics --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 3 --topic users
```

Comment: Yes. I want to know how to setup multiple brokers. https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/installing_cp/zip-tar.html#kafka is the part I'm looking for from your link. I don't know how to implement it.

Comment: So the documentation is there, but if you need more help with it then maybe [this training course](https://www.udemy.com/kafka-cluster-setup/) is worth considering?

Comment: I've amended my answer to list two more URLs re. cluster expansion

Answer (score 1):

There's a simple example of using terraform and ansible to spin up 5 AWS instances and then deploy a 3-broker cluster into it on [GitHub](https://github.com/cjmatta/cp-poc-terraform)

Please note that this is only for playing around with, we need to do some more work to make it more production-like with ELBs in front of the various services you'd want to expose to the internet (REST Proxy, C3).